# What type of tree to use for branches as dinner table legs?

Tags: furniture, natural-wood

I want to make a dinner table with crossed table legs made of tree branches with the bark still on (raw, no stain/finish/veneer). What type of tree would be best to use to make it stable and won't have the bark come of?

Comment: Welcome to Woodworking on StackExchange. This sounds like quite the project. I'm also quite interested (as are many) at keeping a raw look to their wood. Good luck, and may your blades stay sharp!

Comment: There are several comments/answers on [this question](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/119/how-to-finish-a-branch-to-keep-the-bark-partially-on) indicating that the bark will eventually fall off, no matter what kind of wood you use. That could, however, become part and parcel of the project - a "living", evolving dinner table.

Comment: One thing to consider is that branches usually have a lot of tension in them.  This wood is going to be unpredictable as you cut it and as it ages.

Comment: Can you use the trunks of saplings, instead of branches?  Or perhaps the trunks of grapevines?  Many farmers replace their vineyards regularly (due to long-term changes in the markets for varieties of grapes, or pest infestations, or because fruit crop yields tend to drop after about 20 years).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, if you want the bark to stay on, (at least best chance) When is more important than What.  Wood cut in late fall or winter, after the tree goes dormant and before the sap starts flowing again in the spring.

The tree 'dries' itself out and the bark stays attached to the wood much better.  In the spring just when the sap is starting to run is the worst time to try and keep the bark on and the best time to cut wood that you want to peel the bark off.

Oak and Hickory (shag bark) cut in winter will keep it's bark for a long time.